# MongoDB CSharp Driver: How do I deal with "Ensure that known types are derived from the mapped class." error?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have 2 fairly simple classes (map and game), and when I execute this query:

`if(gameCollection.Any(g => g.NumPlayers <GameConstants.MAX_PLAYERS_PER_GAME))`

I get the error: Class MOMGame.GameObjects.Map cannot be assigned to Class MOMGame.GameObjects.Game.  Ensure that known types are derived from the mapped class.
Parameter name: type

Any idea what the problem is? I'm using the latest version of the driver (1.6.0.4624) against Mongo 2.2.

Here are the 2 classes in question:

```
 [BsonKnownTypes(typeof(MOMGame.GameObjects.Map), typeof(MOMGame.GameObjects.Location), typeof(MOMGame.GameObjects.Game), typeof(MOMGame.GameObjects.UserInfo))]
    public class Game 
    {
        [BsonId]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public  Map Map { get; set; }


        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Guid> Players { get; set; }
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
        public int NumPlayers { get; set; }
        public Game()
        {
            Players = new List<Guid>();
            //if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(Game)))
            //{
            //    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Game>(cm => cm.AutoMap());
            //}
        }

        public static void SaveGame(Game game)
        {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost/?safe=true";
            var server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
            var database = server.GetDatabase("mom");
            var gameCollection = database.GetCollection<Game>("games");
            game.NumPlayers = game.Players.Count;
            gameCollection.Save(game);
        }

        public static Game GetNextGame()
        {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost/?safe=true";
            var server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
            var database = server.GetDatabase("mom");
            var gameCollection = database.GetCollection<Game>("games").AsQueryable();
            if(gameCollection.Any(g => g.NumPlayers < GameConstants.MAX_PLAYERS_PER_GAME))
            {
                return gameCollection.First(g => g.NumPlayers < GameConstants.MAX_PLAYERS_PER_GAME);
            }
            else
            {
                return GameCreator.CreateGame();
            }
        }
    }

[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(MOMGame.GameObjects.Map), typeof(MOMGame.GameObjects.Location) , typeof(MOMGame.GameObjects.Game),  typeof(MOMGame.GameObjects.UserInfo))]
    public class Map 
    {
        public Map()
        {
            //if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(Map)))
            //{
            //    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Map>(cm => cm.AutoMap());
            //}
        }
        [BsonIgnore]
        public ILocation[][] Grid { get; set; }

        [BsonId]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnore]
        public List<ILocation> Locations
        {
            get
            {

                List<ILocation> locs = new List<ILocation>();
                for (int i = 0; i < Grid.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Grid[i].Length; j++)
                    {
                        locs.Add(Grid[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                return locs;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the KnownTypes attributes so try removing those. They're for explicitly letting Mongo known of any child classes, and the ones you listed don't seem to be derived from the class the attributes are on